# Rails+jQuery: Get the Value of an Item Inside a Table to Use in a Prepend Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, popup

Say I have a table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover employes_list_panel">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th class="center">Name <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">IQ <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Efficiency <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Focus <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Happiness <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Quality <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Salery <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <%Employe.where(company_id: company.id, request: false).each do |employe|%>
        <tr>
          <td class="center cd-popup-trigger" id="popup3"><i style="color: red;" class="fa fa-close"></i></td>
          <td class="center cd-popup-trigger" id="popup4"><i style="color: green;" class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.name%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.iq%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.efficiency%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.focus%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.happiness%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.quality.capitalize%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.salery%></td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

And I want to get the value of the employe name `<%=employe.name%>` when popup3 for example is clicked. Note there can be more than one "employe" in the list. How can I get the value of the employe that is on the line where the user clicked the popup, so that I can `prepend` it using jQuery into the popup `<p>`.

> Ex:
>
> Click to Open Popup | Kevin |...
>
> Click to Open Popup | Sam |...
>
> I need to get the value Sam when I click the "second popup", the
>   problem is all popups currently have the same id.

Thank  you.

Comment: Have you attempted any code?

Comment: No, because I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Do you know what javascript is?

Comment: @Pabi You are doing it wrong. Firstly, `id` should be unique on a html page.  And secondly I don't see any popup in your `html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code, `popup3` (and `popup4` for that matter) is gonna be present multiple times on the page (once per `tr`). You need to give it a `class`, not an `id`. I personally like to prefix my JavaScript classes (not used for styling) with `js-`. In your HTML:

```
<td class="center cd-popup-trigger js-popup3"><i style="color: red;" class="fa fa-close"></i></td>
```

You also need to identify the cells which contain the employee name (you'll see why later).

```
<td class="center js-employee-name"><%= employe.name %></td>
```

In your JS code, you first need to select the all the `td` with the `js-popup3` class:

```
$('js-popup3')
```

Then, you want to trigger something when an event occurs on the element you selected. With jQuery, you would do it like this:

```
$('js-popup3').on('click', function() {});
```

Lastly, you want to describe what should be done when the event occurs. This is done in the callback function.

```
$('.js-popup3').on('click', function() {
  # employeeName is the value you want
  employeeName = $(this).siblings('.js-employee-name').text();
});
```

I invite you to read a lot about JS (try to code without jQuery first). Once you feel confident with it, start looking at jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a click function for the Table `tr`'s and get the value of the third column (index 2):

```
$('table.reference.notranslate tbody').delegate("tr", "click", function(){
       var YourEmployeName = $(this).find('td').eq(2).text();
       alert(YourEmployeName);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the popups ahve unique id's according to employee try something like this:
    ">

Then I presume you have some js somewhere to handle the popup clicks. This js can extract the employee id with

```
emp_id = my_clicked_popup_trigger.attr("id").split('-')[-1]
```